# Selenium IDE - Extract text string from a variable to create a new variable.

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to extract a text string from a variable and add that into a new command on Selenium IDE. The test suite looks like this -

```
storeAttribute | link=EMQ Welcome Page@href | window
echo | ${window}
```

echo window gives this long piece of text
abcd1ef1526o.ti.jdnv:8350/psp/TULINDI/FINANCE/ENTP/s/WEBLIB_SSO_Z.ISCRIPT1.FieldFormula.IScript_Open_Third_Party?AppType=EMQ&FTPUrl=https%3a//ghij2kl1525m.ti.jdnv/EmqWorkbenchWeb/includes/emqWelcomePage.faces&PORTALPARAM_PTCNAV=Z_EMQ_WELCOME&EOPP.SCNode=ENTP&EOPP.SCPortal=FINANCE&EOPP.SCName=Z_EMQ&EOPP.SCLabel=EMQ&EOPP.SCPTfname=Z_EMQ&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.Z_EMQ.Z_EMQ_WELCOME&IsFolder=false

What i would like to do is extract the part ghij2kl1525m.ti.jdnv (which is a server name) and store that as a new variable. So i have tried like this, but it cant seem to get it to work...

```
store | ${window} | string
store | 1 | delimiter
store | javascript{storedVars['string'].split('a// ')[storedVars['delimiter']]} | test
store | 0 | delimiter1
store | javascript{storedVars['test'].split('ti.jdnv/Emq ')[storedVars['delimiter1']]} | output
echo ${output}
```

This is my echo of output

[info] Executing: |echo | ${output} | |

[info] echo: javascript{storedVars['test'].split('.ti.jdnv/Emq ')[storedVars['delimiter1']]}

Obvioulsy, what im expecting is for $output to be ghij2kl1525m.ti.jdnv.
Is it possible to feed in a variable to that list on commands like that and where am i going wrong?

Any help greatly apprecicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 'store' to 'storeEval' in 3rd and 5th line